# Which parameters of Tesseract 4.0 apply to the LSTM neural network?

Tags: tesseract

I spent some time trying to make a trained neural network use the `tessedit_char_whitelist` and `tessedit_char_blacklist`. However, these parameters are completely ignored and only used for the classic tesseract algorithm (Engine Mode `OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY`).

Is there a list which parameters apply to TESSERACT and which to LSTM?